# Reference for a paper of Jutila

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

Does anyone know where I might be able to locate on the internet the following paper of Jutila?:

M. Jutila, Mean value estimates for exponential sums. Number Theory, Ulm 1987, 120-136.

Comment: It's available by [SpringerLink](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0086549). Can you access it? If not, I can send you a copy.

Comment: many pages of this article can be read on [Google Books](https://books.google.nl/books?hl=en&lr=&id=iKd7CwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA120)